# I tried to display data that are in the database

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to display data that are already in the database i passed these data in to a table like this

```
 <?php
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            var_dump($row);
                            //echo $last_id;
                                '<tr>
                                <td> ' . $row['ord_id'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['ord_total'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['ord_date'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['ord_qty'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_id'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_price'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field1'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field2'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field3'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field4'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field5'].'</td>
                                </tr>';
                            var_dump($row);
                        }

                        ?>
```

i used var_dump($row) in several places it returns data but that data is not displaying in the table

Comment: Did you call session_start() before set session? Did you check product.php run before cart.php or versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, what you want to do, but I think, that you want to set `last_id` to `$_SESSION` and then use it to `cart.php`, If I am right, you have to change your product.php code and to set `$_SESSION['last_id']` before redirect via `header()`, like this:

```
    if (mysqli_query($con, $insert)) 
            {
                $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
                $_SESSION['last_id'] = $last_id; // check this row
                echo '<script>alert("Order added to cart")</script>';
                header("Location: ../neo/cart.php");
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "Error: " . $insert . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
            }
        }
    }

$last_id = $_SESSION['last_id'];
```

Comment: sure i updated the question can you please take a look at it

Comment: @CraftCover Dude, please don't do this. Please return the old question and ask new one about this problem :)